# How can I improve the structure / design of my API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, design-patterns

I was wondering if I could get some software design advice. Hypothetically, let's say that I'm writing an unofficial API for Reddit that lets you log into a Reddit account and manage it, manage messages, view account information, etc., with a wide array of features.

This is the typical pattern I use. All of the code is simplified and dumbed down.

```py
class HTTPClient:
    def __init__(self, session: requests.Session = None):
        if not self.session:
            self.session = requests.Session()
        else:
            self.session = session
    
    def _request(self, method, url, **kwargs):
        """Internal request handler"""
        resp = self.session.request(method, url, **kwargs)
        if resp.ok:
            return  resp
        raise Exception(resp, resp.text)

class RedditSession(HTTPClient):
    """Establishes a Reddit session and does the authentication stuff"""
    def __init__(self, username:str, password: str, session: requests.Session = None):
        super().__init__(session)
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

    def _authentication_stuff_here(self):
        self._request("get", "https://example.com")
        pass    
    
    def _login(self):
        pass
    
class RedditClient(RedditSession)
    def __init__(self, username:str, password: str, session: requests.Session = None):
        super().__init__(username, password, session)
        self._login(self):
    
        # Profile intance contains methods to manage profile info
        self.profile = Profile(self.session)
    
    # Manage account info (not profile info)
    def get_account_information(self):
        pass

    def change_account_password(self, password: str):
        pass
    
    def change_account_email(self, email: str):
        pass
```

I was wondering if anyone knew if this structure was considered bad design, and if anyone had any ideas on how I could improve it.

What particularly bothers me is the multiple layers of indirection; i.e., it feels repetitive to pass an optional `session` instance (or some other variable) through multiple parents. Also, things begin to feel even more messy when I pass the `session` to multiple other classes when using composition.

For example, what if I want to separate methods in a way that a user can type `user.profile.message.delete()`? Would it be normal practice to pass `session` to the `Profile` instance, which then passes it to the `Message` instance? Or is there a better way of achieving this without so many layers of abstraction?

I have tried various design patterns, but everything always feels "messy" in the end. Maybe it's due to my lack of OOP knowledge. Thank you in advance for any help/advice.

Comment: Imho, subclassing `HTTPClient` seems unnecessary - while `RedditSession` will have an `HTTPClient` instance, it seems like its functionality is significantly different so it shouldn't be a subclass.  But it's a subjective choice.  Going further, why not use just a single class?

Comment: @craigb The reason is because there are other parts of the API that also inherit from `HTTPClient` but don't require authentication. For instance, `RedditAPI` (not `RedditClient`) can utilize the same request handler since the error codes and whatnot are the same across Reddit, but it doesn't need all of the extra authentication functionality. 

`HTTPClient` and `RedditSession` are ~200-250 lines of code each, so I figured it would also be best to separate the functionality. One class is just meant for handling requests / errors, and the other is used to complete the authentication process.

Comment: If you can post the real working code, rather than a "simplified and dumbed down" version, you are likely to get more help at https://codereview.stackexchange.com.